# Should I learn Classical Physics if I want to learn Quantum Physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, education

I don't remember anything from school, so please what do you say about the title?

Comment: Just one word: yes.

Comment: I agree with  jinawee: YES.

Comment: Not sure that I agree with the downvotes, but to have a solid understanding of quantum mechanics would require having the solid backing of Hamiltonian mechanics (a branch of classical mechanics). So the answer is a big YES.

Comment: A better question is CAN you learn quantum physics without learning classical physics?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the standard "roadmap" to learning quantum physics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19262/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least a rudimentary understanding of classical physics in order to even understand why quantum physics is useful/important.  That being said, you can learn them both at the same time.

If you are interested in physics, pick up whatever book interests you the most and start learning.  When you run into concepts from other areas of physics that are necessary, you will have to take a break in order to learn them.  Don't get discouraged along the way; learning physics takes a lot of effort and dedication, but the payoff is well worth it!