# Some guidance regarding starting QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education

What prerequisite knowledge do I need for starting QM?
I know basic calculus of class 12th standard (pre college). I am aware of methods of substitutions, standard integrals, definite integrals, integration by part and have a good idea about functions. I also know quite a bit of matrices an linear algebra, vectors , 3d geometry, etc. now my question is, what  extra knowledge do I need to delve into QM and how much more  and what else do I need to start learning QM?
Please answer my question and please do not make fun of me for being a novice.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16814/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19262/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38963/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Linear Algebra and Probability Theory.

Comment: The mathematical heart of the subject is linear algebra - work through a really good course, at the level of, say, Lang's Linear Algebra (the undergraduate book). Fewer matrices and more linear maps! Know about unitary operators, dual vectors, eigenvalues/eigenvectors, diagonalization/normal form. Additionally, it may also help to know some basic functional analysis - distributions in particular, since they are often used in introductory books. A lot of the rest you should be able to pick up as it comes. A good book is by Sakurai.