# From where a person should start about quantum mechanics from very beginning?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

*I am confuse about the learning of quantum mechanics. Basically i am a high school student but i am passionate about quantum mechanics but the main thing is I am confuse about from where should i start*

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19262/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Why not start with a standard quantum mechanics textbook?

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, you should start from the very beginning, means the last decade of the 1800s where classical mechanics start to fail with the description of the "black body radiation". We can say that the idea of quantum mechanics start tryng to solve this problem. The problem was solved by Planck (see [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law)). Start from this you have to know that quantum mechanics requires a math's level which very probably is not covered in an high school's course of math. At same time, before understand q.m. you should study and appreciate the Classical Mechanics and the Electrodynamic, this "subjects" are studied in the first two years of any bachelor's physics degree.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "last decade of the '800s" makes no sense. I tried to edit it to "1800s" - i.e. last decade of the 19th century - but that edit was reverted.

Comment: @gandalf61 Italians refer to centuries that way.

Comment: @Ghoster Then I think most people reading this will be as confused as I was.

Comment: @gandalf61 Agreed. Daniele should not have reverted your edit.