# Study Basic Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education, mathematics

What is the appropriate mathematical background someone must attain in order to enroll in a quantum physics course for beginners?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the math knowledge necessary for starting Quantum Mechanics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16814/)