# About learning quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education

I am looking to learn quantum physics and I know a few things I need to learn but do I  need to learn algebraic trig to learn quantum mechanics?

Comment: What is "algebraic trig"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the math knowledge necessary for starting Quantum Mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16814/)

Comment: Trigonometry with algebra stuff in it, Prameet Srivastava.