# Which book/s should I get before introducing myself to quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

I am in secondary school and have no prior knowledge of quantum mechanics except what it is about and I started gaining interest in the subject so I was wondering which book/s I should get so I will understand better the subject e.g the mathematics used in the subject.

Comment: Google "quantum mechanics for beginners" and or look at some youtube videos on the same subject and see how much you understand. But be aware that it might be a bit of a stretch for a secondary school student....

Comment: Sean Carroll, *Something deeply hidden*. But please promise not sign up to any of the different interpretations of QM before you have worked through a lot of hard maths.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16814/2451 and links therein.

Comment: First (unless you are already up to speed on this) learn some linear algebra.

Comment: What is "secondary school" ?  Different countries have different terminologies for educational levels.

Answer (score 0):

For a general overview (but without much mathematics) try *[The Quantum Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quantum_Universe)* by Brian Cox and Jeff Forshaw. Or for a more detailed introduction, *The New Quantum Universe* by Tony Hey and Patrick Walters (despite the similarity in titles, these two books are not related to one another).

Carlo Rovelli's *[Helgoland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helgoland_(book))* gives a historical introduction, although it also promotes Rovelli's own interpretation of QM, which is called [relational quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_quantum_mechanics).

For a more mathematical treatment, *Quantum Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum* by Leonard Susskind and Art Friedman is a good place to start, although it does assume a basic knowledge of calculus and linear algebra.

Comment: I had to balance the negative impression of this answer that was left by an earlier and unidentified participant, because Rovelli (an Italian) currently writes as well as anyone that I (an American-born interpreter) have ever read in English, and "Helgoland" is up to his usual extremely high standard. It's light on the math, but it was the near-duplicate question that wanted more specifically mathematical recommendations.