# Book recommendation on Quantum Mechanics which is a bit mathematically aligned and gives good introduction to Hilbert Space for beginners

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, mathematics

I am a 4th-year undergraduate student and I have fully read R. Shankar's book on Quantum Mechanics and Griffiths book Quantum Mechanics. I have also done a bit of the Application of QM on multielectron systems,molecules, etc.

Not going ahead in the application part, I want to focus on the foundations of QM part which I find really interesting. But I have very limited knowledge of mathematics. I have read Curtis "An introduction to Linear Algebra", Gallian "Group Theory"(1-10 chapters only) and have a little bit of knowledge on differential geometry.

With this as my Mathematical background, which would be the best book (a bit mathematical) for introduction to Quantum Mechanics which includes an introduction to Hilbert Space and functional analysis?

PS: My question is specifically for the ones who have limited mathematical knowledge in contrast to answers which assumes you have done graduate level mathematics.

Comment: Try Bryan Hall's Quantum Theory for Mathematicians

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22409/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43515/2451 and links therein.

Comment: In one volume would be the QM book by Nair, or extended by Manoukian, or in two volumes the QM book by Galindo and Pascual.

Comment: Note that the [reopen review for this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/277877) has concluded. It is likely that the reviewers thought that your edits don't make this distinct enough from the linked duplicates to be reopened. Please have a *thorough* look at the resources in those linked threads, many of them fulfil the criteria you've specified here. If they don't fit what you need, then re-edit this thread to explain *in detail* why they're insufficient and what things you're looking for in a resource that the existing links don't satisfy.