# Recommended books for introduction to Quantum Mechanics for students who are mathematically aligned

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, mathematics

I am a 4th-year undergraduate student and I have fully read R. Shankar's book on Quantum Mechanics and Griffiths book Quantum Mechanics. I have also done a bit of the Application of QM on multielectron systems,molecules, etc.

Not going ahead in the application part, I want to focus on the foundations of QM part which I find really interesting. But I have very limited knowledge of mathematics. I have read Curtis "An introduction to Linear Algebra", Gallian "Group Theory"(1-10 chapters only) and have a little bit of knowledge on differential geometry.

With this as my Mathematical background, which would be the best book (a bit mathematical) for introduction to Quantum Mechanics which includes an introduction to Hilbert Space and functional analysis?

PS: This not the duplicate of referred links as this is particularly for ones who don't have much mathematical background as opposed to other questions which assumes one to know much mathematics.

Comment: i) Feynman's lectures on physics - Vol III
ii) Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics
iii) John Von Neumann's Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics

Comment: Previously by OP, closed as a duplicate and then deleted by OP: [Book recommendation on Quantum Mechanics which is a bit mathematically aligned and gives good introduction to Hilbert Space for beginners](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509923/).

Comment: Deleting your questions and re-posting them is considered an abuse of this site. If your questions get closed, fix them, and they will be reopened. For the question linked above, you need to explain in detail why the answers in the linked duplicates don't meet your criteria. Keep in mind that [not all resource-recommendations are on-topic here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4698), and there is no guarantee that your modifications to the existing threads make it distinct enough that it is allowed under the site rules.

Comment: I have explained why my question was different from the mentioned duplicates in post scriptum.

Comment: @RandomXYZ Emilio's point mostly revolves around not reposting the question, and editing the old one instead.  You should have added the explanation into the old question, not deleted it and reposted with the additional comment.

Comment: @JMac sorry i didn't know that. From now onwards i will

Comment: @RandomXYZ Questions that are put on hold here can and do get reopened once the problems with them are fixed. Deleting and re-posting removes the previous conversation and forces additional overhead on site moderation, so it is considered an abuse of this site's moderation mechanisms. You should undelete the previous version, edit it to explain why the existing answers don't fit your requirements, and wait for it to be reopened. Your added postscript here goes *some* of the way, but I don't think it's enough, as written.

Comment: And, again: not all resource-recommendations questions are on-topic here. (This is a big step up from the previous step of affairs, where they were completely banned.) If your question remains closed, then it's because it's not distinct enough from the existing threads (i.e., say, the intro-to-QM resources already fill the requirements you've set out). Deleting and re-posting questions to try to get around closures is not OK.