# What is a good target to aim for when teaching myself quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I'm interested in teaching myself quantum mechanics, and I'm looking for a good goal to aim for.

I've got an undergrad maths degree and a graduate degree in probability theory and stochastic processes. I've worked fairly extensively with diffusion processes, so I understand how the Fokker-Planck equation works, for example.

As far as I understand, the Fokker planck equation is related to the Schrodinger equation via something called a Wick rotation. I'm a bit hazy on the details, but I think this may have been Feynman's approach to QM.

If anyone could recommend a text for someone with my background (linear algebra, group theory, ODE and PDE, probability), but with relatively little experience in physics, that would be very helpful.

The maths shouldn't be a problem, but there's a chance I'll just get bored unless I have a specific goal. Maybe deriving the emission spectra of various atoms, or understanding quantum computing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: David Griffiths Intro to Quantum Mechanics

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5014/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Most textbooks of quantum mechanics do not have a very specific goal (otherwise it will be a monograph). You may use Griffiths and Sakurai's modern quantum mechanics as general ones, plus some book in quantum chemistry (for solving various atoms?) and/or quantum computation. Nevertheless if the aim is only for solving hydrogen and possibly helium atoms, Griffiths should be fine...

Comment: Since you seem very interested in probability theory, as a second book, you might want to have a look at Holevo's "Probabilistic and Statistical Aspects of Quantum Theory", which covers what it says, so not all parts of quantum mechanics, but some very essential ones.