# Resources for theory of distributions (generalized functions) for physicists

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

I am looking for tutorials, articles or books containing theory of [distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29) in context of mathematical physics. Please suggest.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/20314/13917 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/13711/11127 Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/125917/2451

Comment: One of the appendices to Mukhanov's recent textbook on quantum effects in gravity gives a nice intro to the theory of distributions: I found it very enlightening

Comment: @Danu I found it informative.

Comment: a bit old but a good one by Garding and Lions is https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02724838

Answer (score 3):

I found following books useful:

1. [A Guide to Distribution Theory and Fourier Transforms](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Guide_to_Distribution_Theory_and_Fouri/T7vEOGGDCh4C)  By Robert S. Strichartz.  Not very rigorous and not much content either. But good book to start from.
2. [Generalized Functions: Theory and Applications](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Generalized_Functions/LXP_8Y0jH88C) By Ram P. Kanwal. Not very rigorous. This book starts with chapter on Dirac delta function and then slowly builds the theory. There are many chapters on applications in Physics and Engineering.
3. [Equations of Mathematical Physics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Equations_of_Mathematical_Physics/-zIZAQAAIAAJ) by V. S. Vladimirov. Rigorous and Pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the books already listed there is the nice (excellent in my opinion) textbook by Friedlander and Joshi, [Introduction to the theory of Distributions](http://www.amazon.it/Introduction-Theory-Distributions-F-Friedlander/dp/0521649714)